# How to delete the last page in Crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports

I cannot figure out how to get rid of the last page in the Crystal report, whether in the report itself or in C# code behind it.

I know how to delete the last blank page if the report has grouping and use `Not OnLastRecord`. But this is not my case, I don't have grouping, and I need to delete the last page regardless whether it's blank or not. I also know how to suppress the header on the last page and use `PageNumber=TotalPageCount`, but this doesn't delete the page.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: how do you decide last page? if there is only one page then what is your expection with the report?

Comment: this is an odd OP for a crystal. what's the contents of the last page?

Comment: Thank you. I know it's odd, but this report has a pretty complicated logic, so under certain conditions I need to delete the last page. The report has many pages. There should be a way to remove or hide the last page, perhaps in C# code, but I cannot find it.

Comment: why this is not working `PageNumber=TotalPageCount` what issue you are facing in this

Answer (score 1):

The usual cause of a blank last page is that you have a report footer section with nothing in it.  Suppress that section.

Another potential cause is a group footer section set to "New Page After".  Make that option conditional with "NOT OnLastRecord"

Comment: Thank you, but like I said in my original message - this is not my case. I don't have grouping, and the last page is not necessarily blank. I just need to know how to remove the last page regardless what's on it.